# How to write linq query to get the result table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

Table:

```
ID      State   Rate
2       NY      8
1       CA      10
1       NY      9
2       IL      7
2       WA      8
1       WA      5
```

Linq Result Table:

```
ID      State   ApprovedR   Not-ApprovedR
2       NY          8           9
1       CA          0           10
2       IL          7           0
2       WA          8           5
```

Rate with record of `ID=1` is considered as `Not-ApprovedR,`
If a record doesn't have and `ID` of 1 then its `Not-ApprovedR` should be shown as 0

Comment: thanks stephen I am new to stack overflow. I didnt know how to put a table in the question

Comment: Cant make sense of this. Your 2nd record has `ID = 1` which you say should have its `Rate` in the `Not-ApprovedR` column, yet that is not what the 2nd table shows (its in the `ApprovedR` column

Comment: All rows should either have `ApprovedR` or `Not-ApprovedR` set to `0` right? *Edit: You kinda need to define your requirements clearly in your post and try showing what have you tried so far.

Comment: No if a state has two ID's  1 and 2 then those corresponding rate should be shown, if it is 2 it should be shown under approvedR if 1 on not-approvedR.

suppose the state has only ID=2, where 2 indicates the rate is an approved rate, so in the resultant table under Not-Approved it should be 0

Comment: Now you have corrected the last 2 columns, can you explain the first - you have 2 NY records, and are grouping them but the first column shows `2` even though one of those records has `ID = 1` - why is the value not `1` for example (surely that column should be omitted)

Comment: In Id 1 and 2 priority is for approved i.e 2, so if a state doesnt have 2 then only 1 shown, if 2 is present 1 is not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a view model to represent you 2nd table structure

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int ApprovedR { get; set; }
    public int Not-ApprovedR { get; set; }
}
```

Then use a `.GroupBy()` to group by `State` and project the result into your view model

```
var data = db.yourTable.GroupBy(x => x.State).Select(x => new MyViewModel()
{
    ID = x.Max(y => y.ID),
    State = x.Key,
    ApprovedR = x.Where(y => y.ID != 1).Sum(y => y.Rate),
    Not-ApprovedR = x.Where(y => y.ID == 1).Sum(y => y.Rate),
});
```

Side note. Naming a field `ID` when its not a unique identifier is confusing, and I recommend you change the name of that property.